# Firestore Query Document's Subcollection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm learning Flutter/Dart and trying to connect to my Firestore database. I want to query a collection for a document, then a collection within that document. I'm still learning Dart but what I've found is that async stream building should be the best method.

I have tried `db.instance.collect('').document('').collection('').snapshot()` but streambuilder doesn't seem to support this and I get the error

> The method 'collection' isn't defined for the type 'Query'.

I have to end my query after `db.instance.collection('').where('name' isEqualto: 'Name').snapshots()`

Below is an example.

My goal is to query all of the classes and present them in a list.

Example -  
 Teachers <-- 1st
Collection
     Teacher Name <--Document within collection 
  Classes <---Collection 2 
    Class1 <-- Query This 
     Class2 <---Query
This

```
       import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
       import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
       
       class ClassListPage extends StatelessWidget{
         @override
       
       
         Widget build(BuildContext context){
           return Material(
                 child: new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
               stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Teachers').
               where('name', isEqualTo: 'Dr. Who')
              //.collection('Classes') <--This is not working
               .snapshots(),
               //HERE is where I want to query for the 'classes' collection then query
           //for the documents within
               builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                 if(!snapshot.hasData)return new Text('..Loading');
                 return new ListView(
                   children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document){
                     return new ListTile( 
                       title: new ListTile(
                         title: new Text(document['name']),
       
                       ),
                     );
                     
                   }).toList(),
                   );
               }
       
             ),
           );
           
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you say that you're using `db.instance.collection('').document('').collection('').snapshot()`, but in your code, there is no call to `document()`.  Here's what I see:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('Teachers')
    .where('name', isEqualTo: 'Dr. Who')
    .collection('Classes')
    .snapshots()
```

This isn't going to work because `where()` returns a Query, and Query doesn't have a `collection()` method.  It sounds like what you need to do instead is execute that query, look at the documents in the result set (there could be any number, not just 1), then make anoterh query for each document's subcollections.

Comment: This is not working code. The issue is I cannot query for collection('Classes'). The working query is .instance.collection('Teacher').where('name' = 'Dr.Who).snapshot(). I cannot include a second collection query for some reason. I am still learning how to take the snapshot I get and query it again from there. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Right, and my answer is saying that you need to execute that working query, iterate the documents in the results, and execute another query for the subcollection of the documents from the first query.